# How can i redirect to a one servlet from a two jsp page?

Tags: servlets

how to redirect from  one servlet to another two jsp file

```
try {
        HttpSession session =request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("phonevalues", modal);
        response.sendRedirect("newdis.jsp");
        response.sendRedirect("discondis.jsp");
        response.sendRedirect("redisp.jsp");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Suggest the give some method ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change page design. Create a web-page that includes one or more views/JSPs. You may use `<jsp:include />` action or `<%@ include %>` directive:

pageTest.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="newdis.jsp"/>
<jsp:include page="discondis.jsp"/>
<jsp:include page="redisp.jsp"/>
```

and redirect pageTest.jsp,

```
HttpSession session =request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("phonevalues", modal);
response.sendRedirect("pageTest.jsp");
```

Comment: thank you.single jsp file two or more form is there .how can diferentiate.give code syntax ??